# Container to store anonymous methods

Tags: delphi, containers, anonymous-methods

I have a following definition.

```
type
  TOmniTaskDelegate = reference to procedure(const task: IOmniTask);
```

What type of container should I use (should be supported in D2009) to store a list of TOmniTaskDelegate instances? Currently I'm using `array of TOmniTaskDelegate` but I'm not really happy with that.

Comment: Why aren't you happy with the array?

Comment: a) Because I would like to delegate the responsibility to a container with well-defined interface and b) because I now resize the array every time I add something to it. True, I could write a nice wrapper around the array which would know the current size and allocated size etc but then I'm already re-implementing TSomeList<T>  and I'd rather use something provided with Delphi (assuming such thing exists).

Comment: What is `TSomeList<T>`? Couldn't you just use `TSomeList<TOmniTaskDelegate>`?

Comment: TSomeList = either TList, TObjectList or TIDontKnowWhatElseIsSupportedInD2009List

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `TList<TOmniTaskDelegate>`. Since this is typesafe due to the use of generics, it will correctly handle the lifetime issues of its members.

Comment: I'm thinking of `TList<T>` in Generics.Collections. This does deal with the reference counting because it is typesafe. But now I have a nagging doubt that it may not be included in D2009.

Comment: TObjectList is not the proper container since anonymous methods references need to include a reference to the method as well as a reference to the "self" of the interface. In other words the size would be 2 x SizeOf(Pointer).

Comment: @Cosmin That's just a silly mistake, I meant `TList<T>` of course.

Comment: +1. Apparently the generic `TList<T>` *is* available in Delphi 2009. No need to re-invent the wheel: the generic list is implemented using `array of` so it's guaranteed to be properly finalized and type safe.

Comment: Beware of the situation where you want to remove something from the list by specifying a reference. I once ran into a situation where items weren't removed because Delphi created a different magic auto-anonymous-method-wrapper every time, even for the same methods.

Comment: @Heinrich That's because it was a different reference. Remember that anonymous methods have variable capture.

Comment: @David Adding the same `method of object` multiple times also gives different references. This took me by surprise the first time I encountered it. I thought they would be the same.

Comment: @Heinrich OK, I can see how `method of` could be different from `reference to`.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit*: Delphi 2009 includes the generic `TList<T>`, I assume it's implemented using `array of`, just as the one in Delphi 2010. That makes the `TList<T>` the optimal choice! My original answer stays because it explains why `array of` is a great data structure and why *not* using it is a lot of trouble.

---

Your choice of `array of Anonym` looks very good to me because:

- Anonymous methods are managed entities (implemented using interfaces). They need to be properly finalized.
- The dynamic array is itself a managed type, making sure the anonymous method references are properly finalized.
- Delphi 2010 generic containers are implemented using dynamic arrays, so they're up to the task. But make sure you don't grow your arrays one-by-one, grow in chunks.

If you use anything else for the implementation you'll need to take care of finalizing the references yourself. Examples:

- If you use plain blocks of memory you'll need an destructor that deliberately sets each item to nil (ie: not ZeroMemory or FillChar) so the compiler gets a chance to generate finalization code.
- Records are managed objects, and they could hold references to dynamic methods, but they can only hold a finite number of references, if you need more you'll need to implement a sort of linked list and then you'll need to carefully manage there life cycle.
- Classes suffer all the deficiencies of records, and they add their own layer of overhead on top of that.

Comment: In your case you are implementing a fundamental type (a fundamental new type of list) and I do not believe that the generics and compiler can be trusted not to do something that would mess up the procedure references.  If I was going to use something other than array-of-ProcRef then I would use a TList<Record> and put the procedure reference inside the record type.

Comment: `array of` is fine for the private implementation of a list, but I would never wish to use it as a primary data type. If you can't use `TList<T>` then create your own lookalike.